# Something is calling my function inside a controller multiple times

Tags: angularjs

This function (declared in a controller) is getting called 16 times:

```
$scope.test = function(hour){

    console.log("hi")

}
```

The function is called using a ng-bind in my html template:

```
<span ng-bind="test()"></span>
```

It also seems that what ever i do next (for instance changing the value of a ng-show, somewhere in my app), the call count goes up by 1.

Are there any reasons why this is happening (i think digest cycle), and how can i prevent it? I don't think it's very efficient.

Comment: Use a debugger (F12 in most browsers). Set a breakpoint. Look at the call-stack.

Comment: This is the callstack: $scope.test(hour=undefined)
hb.prototype.functionCall/<(g=l { $$childTail=l, $$childHead=l, $$nextSibling=l, meer...}, h=undefined)
Pe/this.$get</l.prototype.$digest()
Pe/this.$get</l.prototype.$apply(a=function())

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) docs. This is the point of the directive. It is calling your test function every digest.

> The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the
>   specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to
>   update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

If you are using angular 1.3 and don't want that span to update after stabilizing, you can do a one time binding.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.counter = 1;
  
  $scope.increment = function() {
    $scope.counter++;
  }
  
  $scope.test = function(hour) {
    return $scope.counter;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    {{ counter }}
    <div ng-bind="test()"></div>
    <div ng-bind="::test()"></div>
    <button ng-click="increment()">increment</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case the ::test() is stil getting called, and i'm using angular 1.3.11

Comment: Is your function returning a non undefined value? one time bindings will only stop watching after it stabilizes. I guess the other question is, why are you binding that function? I feel like you might be using the wrong directive.

Comment: The only thing the function does is in the example is a console.log("hi"). Seeing "hi" 16 times in my console got me worried. But the function is doing some other calculation and it's doing this 16 times. Even when i a change a ng-class state (somewhere in my app) it does the calculation. I don't understand why...

Comment: hmm, this is strange. If i return something from the function than the one time binding is working. (return "jow" for instance). If i don't return anything from the function than the function gets called 16 times...

Answer (score -1):

use ng-init instead if ng-bind and it will be called the first time 
so instead of

```
<span ng-bind="test()"></span>
```

use this

```
<span ng-init="test()"></span>
```